# Why does this typedef allow me to use a base class pointer-to-member-function in this template?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, typedef

If I attempt to compile the following code in MSVC:

```
template <typename DELEGATE>
void newButton(DELEGATE *obj, int (DELEGATE::*method)(int))
{
    std::function<int(int)> callback = std::bind(
        method, obj, std::placeholders::_1);
    // ...
}

class Base
{
public:
    virtual int test(int f) { return f * f; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    newButton(&d, &Base::test);
}
```

I get a compiler error:

```
'void newButton(DELEGATE *,int (__thiscall DELEGATE::* )(int))' : 
 template parameter 'DELEGATE' is ambiguous
          could be 'Base'
          or       'Derived'
```

This is reasonable.  The template expects an identical type for `obj` and `method`, but they are not exactly the same.

BUT, if I replace the pointer-to-member-function declaration with this template struct typedef, it compiles!

```
template <typename DELEGATE>
struct ButtonAction
{
    typedef int (DELEGATE::*Type)(int);
};

template <typename DELEGATE>
void newButton(DELEGATE *obj, typename ButtonAction<DELEGATE>::Type method)
{
    std::function<int(int)> callback = std::bind(
        method, obj, std::placeholders::_1);
    // ...
}

// rest same as before
```

Why?  I would have expected the typedef to get resolved down to the exact same pointer-to-member-function type, and cause the same template error.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that in `ButtonAction<DELEGATE>::Type`, `DELEGATE` appears in a non-deduced context - the compiler cannot deduce `DELEGATE` from this, so it does not try. Therefore, the deduction is performed from the first argument only, and so it's unambiguous.

As to why `DELEGATE` cannot be deduced in this context - try to imagine what the process would need to be: inspect `ButtonAction<T>` for *every possible* type `T` and compare its nested typedef `Type` against the argument type. And note that there are infinitely many possible types.

A rule of thumb is: everything to the left of `::` is a non-deduced context.

Comment: Thanks for your very helpful answer.  But *why* is it that "in `ButtonAction<DELEGATE>::Type`, `DELEGATE` appears in a non-deduced context - the compiler cannot deduce `DELEGATE` from this"?

Comment: @japreiss I've expanded the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the second example, the `method` parameter does not participate in type deduction, so `DELEGATE` is deduced to `Derived`, and `&Base::test` is implicitly converted to `(Derived::*)(int)`.